# Syntax Error, Cant figure out why(Line 17)

Tags: python, loops, iteration

b.  Create a program that simulates a simple savings account simulation.  First ask the user for the initial balance (must be at least $100 and less than $400,000).  As long as the user wants to continue allow them to make deposits and withdrawals – don’t overdraft!  When the user is done, output the final balance.
(suggestion…use a menu something like:
1.  Deposit
2.  Withdrawal
3.  Quit )

```
balance = int(input("Enter initial balance: $ "))

while balance <= 100 or balance >= 400000:
    print ("Invalid Amount!")
    balance = int(input("Ener valid amount: $ "))

deposit = 0
withdraw = 0

if balance >= 100 and balance <= 400000:
    while ans != 3: 
        print("""
    1. Deposit
    2. Withdrawal
    3. Quit
    """)
ans = int(input("What would you like to do? Please enter the appropriate     number. "))
if ans == 1:
    deposit = int(input("\n How much would you like to deposit: $")
    balance = balance + deposit
elif ans == 2:
    withdraw = int(input("\n How much would you like to withdraw: $")
    if (balance - withdraw) < 0
        withdraw = int(input("\n Tried to withdraw too much! How much would  you like to withdraw: $")
        balance = balance - withdraw
elif ans == 3:
print("Your final balance is %d" %balance.)
```

Comment: `if (balance - withdraw) < 0` missing `:`.  Your final `print` statement is not indented, also you have a trailing `.` after `balance`.

Comment: still getting an error at
balance = balance + deposit

Comment: Missing trailing `)` on the line before.  ALWAYS look at the line above where the error is detected.

Comment: And also missing `)` on line 19

Comment: Aren't you using `ans` before defining it? This will result in a NameError.

Comment: thanks guys much appreciated, now that syntax is clear this is what im getting
NameError: name 'ans' is not defined

Comment: @Shashank what should i define <ans> as?

Comment: By defining, I mean you assign it to something before using it in a conditional expression `ans != 3`.

Comment: So i assign IT to something or do i something to IT, I tired ans = 0 before while ans !=3 and it game me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `)` on the previous line, you want:

```
if ans == 1:
deposit = int(input("\n How much would you like to deposit: $"))
```

and an other one:

```
withdraw = int(input("\n How much would you like to withdraw: $"))
```

and then a tailing `:`:

```
if (balance - withdraw) < 0:
```

and another `)` one further on:

```
    if (balance - withdraw) < 0
        withdraw = int(input("\n Tried to withdraw too much! How much would  you like to withdraw: $"))
```

and then a space after your `%` (and get rid of the `.`):

```
print("Your final balance is %d" % balance)
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I got my syntax right but now I am getting a NameError, How should i define ans?

Comment: you need to define `ans` before the `while ans != 3:` something like the line replicated that inputs `ans`

Comment: If i assign it before while ans != 3: it gives me error and if i assign it right after line 6 it runs in infinity loop. Sorry im still new to this

Comment: @HissanMunir Basically you have tons of errors in your code.  You have some work ahead of you... but your not *that* far away.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. I have been trying hard. Just point me in right direction.

Comment: Instead of `while ans != 3:` you want to: set `ans = 0` and then a `while ans not in (1, 2, 3):` block for your `print` statement and your `input` statement for `ans`.  That will get you a step closer.  Then, you *will* want an outer `while ans != 3:` around all of that and the following `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a ')' on line 16.